# How much junk can a douchebag carry?

Tags: south-park-the-stick-of-truth

Having played just a few RPG's before (Diablo II, Oblivion, Skyrim, DoomRL), one thing I've learned is that you can generally only bring a certain amount of stuff with you.
Is there any weight/size limit on douchebag's inventory in The Stick of Truth, or can I collect infinite amounts of pubes and crumpled papers?

Comment: Shouldn't "douchebag" be capitalized, since it is your character's in-character name in the game?

Comment: @Xantec: It might detract from the "out-of-context" effect that I was going for.

Comment: "a douchebag"? You are douchebag. So don't use "a".

Comment: And that's worth a downvote? Your douchebag is not my douchebag, so you could say that my douchebag is just "an" other douchebag.

Comment: @oKtosiTe Don't assume a person who left a negative comment is a downvoter. Don't assume a downvoter left a comment. That way lies madness.

Comment: Indeed I did not downvote... @oKtosiTe

Comment: Sorry for the accusation. I should know better.  @Loko

Comment: And here was I thinking a douchebag would be like a South Park bag of holding :-(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's no limit, other than your own sanity in trying to manage your inventory. In fact, there's even an **Achievement** for completing the game without selling anything, ever.

Comment: Looks like I've already screwed up that achievement. Is there any reason to hold on to the items in your junk?

Comment: Nope. None whatsoever unless you're going for the **For the Horde** achievement mentioned above. Sell it all off for cash.

Comment: There is also an achievement, **Junk Peddler**, for selling 300 junk items. So if you've already sold something, then go wild and sell it all and try **For the Horde** next play-through if you so desire. It is probably worth doing **Make it Rain!** at the same time as you are selling. That requires spending $500.