# The purpose of saving my junk

Tags: south-park-the-stick-of-truth

It does not take long to fill your junk bag with all sorts of South Park reliqs, such as a Cartman or Ming CD - even sex toys and crack.

What I cant figure out, is wether to stash the junk in my toys trunk, or to keep it on me incase it could be needed for something - or even just vendor it.

**Does the junk you find, serve any purpose besides being vendor trash?**

Comment: What you gonna do with all that junk, all that junk inside your trunk?

Comment: Possibly related/duplicate? http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/159218/how-much-junk-can-a-douchebag-carry

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Junk is exactly as you described, **vendor trash**.

One reason for keeping it is for the achievement **For the Horde**. This requires you to not sell a single item (including junk) in a play-through.

If you've already sold some stuff though, not all is lost as there is the achievement, **Junk Peddler**, which requires you to sell 300 pieces of junk. And whilst you are at it, you may as well complete **Make it Rain!** (spend $500) as you will have a lot of cash to spend.

Answer (score 1):

None of the junk will ever be useful.